# Issue with amsart.cls

Tags: texmaker, amsart

I have a problem with "amsart.cls". In particular, when compiling with TexMaker (pdflatex) the following

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I get the following error : ! LaTeX Error: File `amsart.cls' not found.

That's very strange, as I didn't have such a problem yesterday (working on the entire tex file). I tried to update my TexLive to the last version. But this didn't solve the problem... What could I do?

Comment: What version of TeXlive on what OS?

Comment: Version 2022 on Windows 10.

Comment: unrelated but do not set or change `\pdfoutput` manually in your document. You will confuse packages testing the variable. Run pdflatex if you want pdf output.

Comment: Perhaps the filename data base is corrupted. Run `mktexlsr`  once.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what is mktexlsr?